# TypeScript Compiler was given an empty configurations string

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am getting a Warning in the Error List of Visual Studio when building my TypeScript project.

```
The TypeScript Compiler was given an empty configurations string, which is unusual and suspicious.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is caused when this line ...

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
```

... precedes these PropertyGroup sections in the .csproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
  <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
  <TypeScriptRemoveComments>false</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
  <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
  <TypeScriptRemoveComments>true</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
  <TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have extra build configurations in your project, these settings could be missing from those build configurations.  It took me a few minutes to realize this.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the typescript properties mentioned in NYCDotNet's answer were entirely missing for my property group sections.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
blah
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
blah
</PropertyGroup>
```

Adding them as per NYCDotNet fixed it.

Note

- I didn't have this problem in VStudio but when executing MSBuild from the command line.
- Typescript V0.9