# Breakpoints are not working in typescript code when debuging with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, typescript

I am debuging with typescript, Internet Explorer and Visual Studio. Sometimes breakpoint are not working. ("breakpoint will not be currently hit no symbols loaded for this document"). Even computers restart is not help.

I have noticed that breakpoint are woking in some files in others working ok.

Problem fix itself sometimes, but i can't say why. Any hints?

Comment: I don't know, but possibly this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752408/typescript-debug-breakpoint-does-not-work :-)

Comment: Have tried it, but no in my case :(